# Manually deleting connect-mongo session by _id cast error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, express-session, connect-mongo

I'm attempting to manually delete a document from the connect-mongo sessions collection. When I try to delete a document I get the following error:

> message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "gl9-V-bjAjqv2Nwdf9vHPLN_Fnnl4Thz" at path "_id"'

express-session uses the following function to generate a session id:

```
function generateSessionId(sess) {
 return uid(24);
}
```

The session generated from this function is making it way into the _id property of the sessions document. However when you try and find or delete the document by the generated id you get the error.

The mongodb docs say the _id should be

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type
>   [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)

I've tried to override the session id using the genid option on the session, but the override doesn't make it into the database.

How can I get a valid _id onto the document or query the document with an invalid _id?

Thanks!

**My Infrastructure**: Express 4.10, Node v0.12.7, Compose.io, connect-mongo, express-session

Comment: When you say *"..I try to delete a document.."* then what do you mean here? Are you calling `.destroy()` on the session or doing something else? Specifically, have you set up a "mongoose" model to the session store and trying to manipulate through that?

Comment: Yes. I have a mongoose model and I am using Model.remove()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so your problem here is the mongoose model you are using to delete documents from the session store. You probably should be calling `req.session.destroy()` or setting up TTL to remove expired sessions instead.

But basically, mongoose is expecting the "type" of the `_id` field to be an `ObjectId` and as such "autocasts". The `mongo-connect` middleware itself does not use mongoose methods, but talks to the underlying driver methods instead. So it does not have this problem when using it's internal methods.

Your mongoose schema definition should therefore look something  like this:

```
var sessionSchema = new Schema({
    "_id": String,
    "session": String
},{ "_id" false });
```

Or at the very least contain `{ "_id": false }` in order to remove the default autocasting behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my cast error. req.session.destroy() doesn't remove the document from the database. After I call req.session.destroy() I'm attempting to delete the document from the db manually to ensure the session is truly gone.

Comment: @LarryHipp I ddi just quickly set up a vanilla install and swapped out `genid` as `{ genid: function(req) { return uuid.v4() } }` in the configuration using the `node-uuid` package. Everything works fine for me. I would suggest that you have other configuration issues to look at if this is not working for you. You can always post another question about that if you cannot find the issue.